# Incorporating onmouseover event and <a> tag

Tags: javascript, html

This is the code incorporating onmouseover events and  tag:

> You may change the image1.src and image2.src into any image you like

```js
<!--
if (document.image){
 var image1 = new Image();
 image1.src = "Dark Swampert.jpg";
 var image2 = new Image();
 image2.src = "Tulips.jpg";}
 
function printPage(){
 window.print();}
 
//-->
```

```css
body{background-color: aquamarine;}
```

```html
<head><title> Cheater </title></head>
<body>
<p> Move the mouse over the image to see results: </p>
<a href="#" onmouseover="document.myImage.src=image2.src;" onmouseout="document.myImage.src=image1.src;">
<img name="myImage" src="Dark Swampert.jpg" width=120 height=160/>
</a>
<br><input type=button value="Print this Page!" onClick="printPage();"/>
</body>
```

However, when you move the mouse over the image, it says

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of undefined

What is wrong with the code?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Firstly it is not clear where exactly your script is included in your html file.
Secondly please look into `addEventListener` API for adding event listeners rather than using onmouseover attribute.

Comment: It says you are trying to access the `src` of an object non-defined yet on the page, try to use `<body onload="myInitialization()">`, and to use function `myInitialization()` to do some JS stuff.

Comment: My teacher gave me the code only... that's all. And also, I learned only a few basic codes.

Comment: Ok. To do a complete explaination, your JS code is running when the document hasn't loaded all the object that are inside (image, div, ...). So how can the JS change the source of an image that is not already loaded ? To solve this issue, you should wait untill all object in your DOM are loaded, and then applying changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.image` is undefined. I guess you need `document.images`. Though your code is a real mess. :)

```js
<!--
if (document.images){
 var image1 = new Image();
 image1.src = "Dark Swampert.jpg";
 var image2 = new Image();
 image2.src = "Tulips.jpg";}
 
function printPage(){
 window.print();}
 
//-->
```

```css
body{background-color: aquamarine;}
```

```html
<head><title> Cheater </title></head>
<body>
<p> Move the mouse over the image to see results: </p>
<a href="#" onmouseover="document.myImage.src=image2.src;" onmouseout="document.myImage.src=image1.src;">
<img name="myImage" src="Dark Swampert.jpg" width=120 height=160/>
</a>
<br><input type=button value="Print this Page!" onClick="printPage();"/>
</body>
```

Comment: Sorry, just trying to copy-paste the codes my teacher gave me.

Comment: He/she teaches you bad things :). Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

```
var image1 = new Image();
image1.src = "Dark Swampert.jpg";
var image2 = new Image();
image2.src = "Tulips.jpg";
```

image1 and image2 has to be in global scope.